# the exact graph of the general solution for $x'=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 4& 1 \end{bmatrix}x$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

i need someone to give me exact graph  of  the general solution for

$$x'=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\   4& 1 \end{bmatrix}x$$

i solved it manually , the general solution is like this

$$x(t)=c_1\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
2
\end{pmatrix} e^{3t} +c_1\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
-2
\end{pmatrix} e^{-t} $$

and the graph will be something like this
http://prntscr.com/52xmbe

I'll appreciate any help , thanks for advance

Comment: The eigenvectors are perpendicular in the picture, that's not right, just saying.

Comment: lol its like not good pic -,- but its my try , i need exact graph to work  with

Comment: @Amzoti thanks for the link , but i have matrix ao idk how would that work